# How can I switch these two divs using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs that I want to "switch" when I click each button.

The best way to show you is [this example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/dyXY4/).

I have the layout I want and the functionality almost there, but instead of one div being placed on top of the other (I've used `position: absolute;` to have them in the same "space") I want them to "switch out" as I press the buttons.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: So, when you click at Button1, Button1 disappears and But2 appears, and vice versa?

Comment: Exactly, click button 1, div 1 appears, click button 2, div1 disappears and div 2 appears.

Comment: Are you set on having them animate, as in your example?

Comment: @Saturdayplace, yes. I am quiet set on this animated effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind them all with one concise function, taking advantage of `.index()`:

```
$('.menu_ind').click(function() {
    var n = $(".menu_ind").index(this);
    $(".about_me").not(":eq(" + n + ")").animate({
        left: '100%'
    }, 800).end().eq(n).animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/dyXY4/12/

Comment: Great! and will this work for more than just two divs/buttons? Say if I wanted to add more content?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Just make sure your content divs appear in the same order as their corresponding buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Might you be looking for something like this:

http://lab.smashup.it/flip/

Comment: Kind of, but with the slide left and right animation instead of the flipping. Cool resource though, I'll keep it for future use :)

Comment: Perhaps something like http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ instead, the shuffle effect, or you can code your own custom effect, but cycle should allow you to do it.

Answer (score 1):

How about not using toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyXY4/8/

```
$('#clicker1').click(function() {
    $("#about_me").animate({
        left: '-2000px'
    }, 800);
    $("#about_you").animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 800);
});

$('#clicker2').click(function() {
    $("#about_you").animate({
        left: '-2000px'
    }, 800);

    $("#about_me").animate({
        left: '0'
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Exactly. Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dyXY4/9/

```
$('#clicker1').click(function()
{
    if ($("#about_me").css('left') == '2000px')
    {
        $('#about_you').animate({ left: '2000px' }, function ()
        {
            $('#about_me').animate({ left: '0px' });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#about_me').animate({ left: '2000px' });
    }
});

$('#clicker2').click(function()
{
    if ($("#about_you").css('left') == '2000px')
    {
        $('#about_me').animate({ left: '2000px' }, function ()
        {
            $('#about_you').animate({ left: '0px' });
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#about_you').animate({ left: '2000px' });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell all divs to slide out when you click, then just the one you want in to slide in. Here's some jQuery:

```
$(".menu_ind").click(function (e) {
    $('.wrap div').animate({
        left: $(window).width()
    }, 800);
});

$('#clicker1').click(function() {
    $("#about_me").animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 800);
});

$('#clicker2').click(function() {
    $("#about_you").animate({
        left: '0px'
    }, 800);
});
```

You could then tweak your css a little to hide the div that's leaving the screen so you don't see a horizontal scrollbar.

http://jsfiddle.net/jFe2p/

Comment: Much better solution, I already have the overlow on my real implementation. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/) is a really solid tutorial on how to make the effect I believe you are after.

Basically it uses jQuery some plugins witten by [Ariel Flesler](http://flesler.blogspot.com/) and some neat CSS/JavaScript techniques.  Check out the demo [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html).  It even supports `next/prev` as well as loading content given url hashes.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `background-color` to your content divs. Otherwise they'll be transparent. You may also need to adjust your height accordingly.

Comment: This in no way answers my question. I want them to be transparent, and the height is as I wish. The problem is the "switching" of divs.

Comment: Then you need to modify your transition and fade one of the divs out. If you want them to be stacked ontop of each other, and have only one be visible, you'll need to make them opaque. Using your current implementation, this is the solution. And I recommended adjusting the height because your current div doesn't extend to the height of your text.

Comment: Please see AbstractDownvoteFactor, Joe and Rusty Jeans' answers.

Comment: I did, all of which involve making the second div not occupy the same space. My answer is based on your question of having it occupy the same space. I'm surprised to find someone so angry at an individual for trying to help them!

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood or I didn't explain properly but the desired effect is what they have produced, I am not angry, just trying to explain that what you have bought forward in your answer is not my deisred outcome :)